# How do I get USB speakers working on my Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3

This may sound like a duplicate question, but the answers to similar questions are not solving my problem.  I have plugged the USB cable from my Logitech S-150 digital speakers into a powered USB hub connected to my Pi 3.  The speakers show that they're on - "DIGITAL" appears on the one with the controls and cable.  My `aplay -l` output is

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: AUDIO [USB  AUDIO], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I used `sudo nano /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf` to change the `defaults.ctl.card 0
defaults.pcm.card 0` values to 1 as I read in an answer to a similar problem.  I don't know if the speakers are working or the Pi is not recognizing them.  I have used the GUI Audio Device Settings (under Preferences) to set the Control to PCM for both **bcm2835 ALSA (Alsa mixer)(Default)** and **USB AUDIO (Alsa mixer)**.
Is there a way I can test the speakers' output without finding & using an MP3 file with `aplay`?

I issued `wget goo.gl/XJuOUW -O example.mp3 --no-check-certificate` and got -

```
-2016-04-21 14:55:57--  http://goo.gl/XJuOUW
Resolving goo.gl (goo.gl)... 2607:f8b0:4002:c05::66, 216.58.217.238
Connecting to goo.gl (goo.gl)|2607:f8b0:4002:c05::66|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raspberrypilearning/burping-jelly-baby/master/sounds/la.mp3 [following]
--2016-04-21 14:55:58--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raspberrypilearning/burping-jelly-baby/master/sounds/la.mp3
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 23.235.44.133
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|23.235.44.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 17260 (17K) [audio/mpeg]
Saving to: ‘example.mp3’

example.mp3         100%[=====================>]  16.86K  --.-KB/s   in 0.001s 

2016-04-21 14:55:59 (27.5 MB/s) - ‘example.mp3’ saved [17260/17260]
```

I then issued o`mxplayer example.mp3` and got

```
Audio codec mp3 channels 1 samplerate 11025 bitspersample 16
Subtitle count: 0, state: off, index: 1, delay: 0
have a nice day ;)
```

Through my Pi 3's GUI Preferences, I've set both **bcm2835 ALSA (Alsa mixer) (Default)** and **USB AUDIO (Alsa Mixer)**.

Comment: You can test with wget https://goo.gl/XJuOUW -O example.mp3 --no-check-certificate and omxplayer example.mp3

Comment: I heard no sound.  I issued aplay example.mp3 and got Playing raw data 'example.mp3' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono.

Comment: After much more searching for answers and trying a whole bunch of things, my speakers are now working as expected!

Comment: So why not answer your own question and help others.

Answer (score 2):

Just had a similar issue and solved it like this (found in [this](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/develop/python/hardware/audio) tutorial):

Find your playback devices:

Locate your speaker in the list of playback hardware devices. Write down the card number and device number.

```
aplay -l
```

Create a new file named .asoundrc in the home directory (/home/pi). Make sure it has the right slave definitions speaker; use the configuration below but replace `<card number>` and `<device number>` with the numbers you wrote down in the previous step. Do this for pcm.speaker.

```
pcm.!default {
  type asym
  playback.pcm "speaker"
}

pcm.speaker {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm "hw:<card number>,<device number>"
  }
}
```

Comment: The link in the above answer (i.e. shown as "this" tutorial) does not link to the relevant tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

This solved my problem:

> All we have to do is tell Raspbian to look at "card #1" for the default audio. Card #0 is the built in audio, so this is fairly straightforward.
>
> Tun sudo nano /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf and look for the following two lines:
>
> defaults.ctl.card 0
>
> defaults.pcm.card 0
>
> Change both “0” to “1” and then save the file. That’s it!

https://learn.adafruit.com/usb-audio-cards-with-a-raspberry-pi/updating-alsa-config

Answer (score 0):

The answer above (answered Oct 7 '17 at 8:41) solved my USB speaker device problem on Raspberry Pi 4 with OS Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
(bought the speaker from Amazon: a UKHONK Mini USB Speaker Plug-and-Play for Notebook&PC, product model: HK-5002 and in USB listing referred to as GEMBIRD, but probably not mentioned online).

The Adafruit guide for USB speaker installation (that worked for the person that answered on Apr 4 '19 at 14:47) did not work alone for me.

Thanks for the tips! (Have not, however, rebooted the Pi yet...)